# I can listing files on directory, but i want to remove last character on Response.write

Tags: file-io, asp-classic

i have this script to list directory files. But i need to remove the last character, in that case, a comma, from the Response.Write. How to do??

Here is my code:

```
<% ListFolderContents(Server.MapPath("apresentacoes/braspress")) %>
<% sub ListFolderContents(path)

     dim fs, folder, file, item, url

     set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
     set folder = fs.GetFolder(path)

    'Display the target folder and info.

     Response.Write("<h2>"& folder.Name &"</h2>")

     'Display a list of sub folders.

     for each item in folder.SubFolders
                ListFolderContents(item.Path)
     next

     'Display a list of files.
    for each item in folder.Files
       url = MapURL(item.path)
       Response.Write("""" & item.Name & """,")
    next
    end sub   


   function MapURL(path)

     dim rootPath, url

     'Convert a physical file path to a URL for hypertext links.

     rootPath = Server.MapPath("/")
     url = Right(path, Len(path) - Len(rootPath))
     MapURL = Replace(url, "\", "/")

end function %>
```

Here is the output:

```
braspress

"1.jpg","2.jpg","3.jpg","capa.jpg",
```

And i need this:

```
braspress

"1.jpg","2.jpg","3.jpg","capa.jpg"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dim myfiles

for each item in folder.Files
   url = MapURL(item.path)
   myFiles = myFiles & item.Name & ","
next

myfiles = left(myfiles, len(myfiles)-1)

Response.Write myfiles
```

Comment: Perfect. But i need to modify the `len(myfiles)-1` to `len(myfiles)-2` because I use space after comma. Thanks!!